# nonlinear optimization with vectors, scalars and inequality constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have set of equation in form: Y=aA+bB 
where Y-is know vector of floats (only this one is known!); a, b are unkown scalar (float) and A, B are unknown vectors of floats. Each equation have it own Y, a, b, whereas all equation share the same unknow vectors A and B.

I have set of such equation so my problem is to minimize function:
(Y-aA-bB)+(Y'-a'A-b'B)+....
I have also many inequality constrains of type: Ai>Aj (Ai i-th element of vector A), Bi>= Bk, Bi>0, a>a', ...

Is there any software or library (ideally for python) which can handle this problem?

Comment: what have you researched so far? have you looked into numpy?

Answer (score 4):

#### General remarks

This is a **linear** problem (at least in the linear least-squares sense, continue reading)!

It's also incompletely specified as it's not clear if there should be always a feasible solution in your case or if you want to minimize some given loss in general. Your text sounds like the latter, but in this case one has to chose the loss (which makes a difference in regards to possible algorithms). Let's take the euclidean-norm (probably the best pick here)!

Ignoring constraints for a moment, we can view this problem as basic **least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation** problem (euclidean-norm vs. squared euclidean-norm does not make a difference!).

```
min || b - Ax ||^2
```

Here:

```
M = number of Y's
N = size of Y
b = (Y0,
     Y1,
     ...) -> shape: M*N (flattened: Y_x = (y_x_0, y_x_1).T)
A = ((a0, 0, 0, ..., b0, 0, 0, ...),
     (0, a0, 0, ..., 0, b0, 0, ...),
     (0, 0, a0, ..., 0, 0, b0, ...),
     ...
     (a1, 0, 0, ..., b1, 0, 0, ...)) -> shape: (M*N, N*2)
x = (A0, A1, A2, ... B0, B1, B2, ...) -> shape: N*2 (one for A, one for B)
```

#### What you should do

- If **unconstrained**:

  - Convert to standard-form and use numpy's [lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)
- If **constrained**:

  - Either use customized optimization algorithms, or:

    - **Linear-programming** (if minimizing absolute-differences / l1-norm)

      - I'm too lazy to formulate it for scipy's [linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog)
      - Not that hard, but l1-norm is non-trivial using scipy's API
      - Much easier to formulate with [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org) (`obj=cvxpy.norm(X, 1)`)
    - **Quadratic-programming / Second-order-cone-programming** (if minimizing euclidean norm / l2-norm)

      - Again, too lazy to formuate it; no special solver available at scipy yet
      - Could be easily formulated with cvxpy (`obj=cvxpy.norm(X, 2)`)
    - Emergency: use general-purpose constrained nonlinear-optimization algorithms like *SLSQP* -> see code

#### Some hacky code (not the best approach!)

This code:

- Is just a demo!
- Uses general nonlinear optimization algorithms from scipy

  - Therefore:

    - easier to formulate
    - Less fast & robust than LP, QP, SOCP
    - But will achieve approximately the same result as convergence on *convex optimization problems* is guaranteed
  - Uses automatic-differentiation whenever needed

    - (author too lazy to add gradients)
    - this can really hurt if performance is important
- Is really ugly in terms of np.repeat vs. broadcasting!

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
np.random.seed(1)

""" Fake-problem (usually the job of the question-author!) """
def get_partial(N=10):
    Y = np.random.uniform(size=N)
    a, b = np.random.uniform(size=2)
    return Y, a, b

""" Optimization """
def optimize(list_partials, N, M):
    """ General approach:
        This is a linear system of equations (with constraints)
        Basic (unconstrained) form: min || b - Ax ||^2
     """
    Y_all = np.vstack(map(lambda x: x[0], list_partials)).ravel()       # flat 1d
    a_all = np.hstack(map(lambda x: np.repeat(x[1], N), list_partials)) # repeat to be of same shape
    b_all = np.hstack(map(lambda x: np.repeat(x[2], N), list_partials)) # """

    def func(x):
        A = x[:N]
        B = x[N:]
        return np.linalg.norm(Y_all - a_all * np.repeat(A, M) - b_all * np.repeat(B, M))

    """ Example constraints: A >= B element-wise """
    cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
             'fun' : lambda x: x[:N] - x[N:]})

    res = minimize(func, np.zeros(N*2), constraints=cons, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})
    print(res)
    print(Y_all - a_all * np.repeat(res.x[:N], M) - b_all * np.repeat(res.x[N:], M))


""" Test """
M = 4
N = 3
list_partials = [get_partial(N) for i in range(M)]
optimize(list_partials, N, M)
```

Output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 0.9019356096498999
            Iterations: 12
            Function evaluations: 96
            Gradient evaluations: 12
     fun: 0.9019356096498999
     jac: array([  1.03786588e-04,   4.84041870e-04,   2.08129734e-01,
         1.57609582e-04,   2.87599862e-04,  -2.07959406e-01])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 96
     nit: 12
    njev: 12
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 1.82177105,  0.62803449,  0.63815278, -1.16960281,  0.03147683,
        0.63815278])
[  3.78873785e-02   3.41189867e-01  -3.79020251e-01  -2.79338679e-04
  -7.98836875e-02   7.94168282e-02  -1.33155595e-01   1.32869391e-01
  -3.73398306e-01   4.54460178e-01   2.01297470e-01   3.42682496e-01]
```

I did not check the result! If there is an error it's an implementation-error, not a conceptional one (my opinion)!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I'm not sure what you mean by:
x = N*2 (one for A, one for B)

Comment: Scipy's optimizers are build for a vector of unknows (not multiple vectors). This also applies to these algebraic matrix-forms i introduced. Instead of using two optimization vectors ```A=[a0, a1, a2, ...]```, ```B=[b0, b1, b2, ...]```, we just use one: ```X=[a0, a1, a2, ..., b0, b1, b2]```. And as ```shape A == shape Y``` -> ```A``` has ```N``` elements and ```B``` too; ```shape X = N*2```

Comment: thx. Correct me if I'm wrong: I need to force A to stay in form you wrote by (quite big) set of constrains. So, I need to i) fix all zero's element to 0 (which is easy in each library) and ii) somehow (I have not found how yet) force several element of matrix A to be equal each other (e.g. A(0,0)=A(1,1)=A(2,2) which is a0 and so on)

Comment: It all depends on what you are doing exactly. This form is the one for linear least-.squares (compatible with numpy's API; i don't know if the word constraint is correct, that's the origin of my remarks at the beginning); LP/QP will look a bit different as we need 1 aux-vars to grab the loss.

Comment: Back to your remarks: Ideally it should be one solution but in my model I expect it should be more that one solution. Without constrains number of solution will be huge. The constrains is kind of heuristics aimed to reduce number of solutions. I can start either all random or use reasonable initial values for A and B. A priori it is not possible to say which is better. I need to make so correlation to test my model.
I dont want to go into physical sens of model, it is quite complex and not relevant to my question. I want to find some local minimum for given initial value of a, b, A, B.

Comment: What? It's a simple convex problem. Every local minimum is a global one. And in the least-squares approach (euclidean-norm), there is only one solution if our A is of full-rank.

Comment: Now I really confused. I dont know you mean by "what?". Sentence "Every local minimum is a global one" is true only if all local minima have exactly the same value (so call degenerated states). 
I asked if I need to set constrains to A (as described in second comment). I have some doubts about this part of your answer.

Comment: I already mentioned that the lstsq and for example qp-approach look different and in the former i would not call them constraints. You still did not tell us what approach you are trying to use and with what library. So i really can't follow you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with sascha that this is a linear problem. As I do not like constrains very much, I prefer, actually, to make it a non-linear without constrains. I do so by setting the vector `A=(a1**2, a1**2+a2**2, a1**2+a2**2+a3**2, ...)` like this it is ensured that it is all positive and `A_i > A_j` for `i>j`. That makes errors a bit problematic, as you now have to consider error propagation to get `A1`, `A2`, etc. including correlation, but I will have an important point on that at the end. The "simple" solution would look as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from random import random
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=190)


def generate_random_vector(n, sortIt=True):
    out=np.fromiter( (random() for x in range(n) ),np.float)
    if sortIt:
        out.sort()
    return out


def residuals(parameters,dataVec,dataLength,vecDims):
    aParams=parameters[:dataLength]
    bParams=parameters[dataLength:2*dataLength]
    AParams=parameters[-2*vecDims:-vecDims]
    BParams=parameters[-vecDims:]
    YList=dataVec
    AVec=[a**2 for a in AParams]##assures A_i > 0
    BVec=[b**2 for b in BParams]
    AAVec=np.cumsum(AVec)##assures A_i>A_j for i>j
    BBVec=np.cumsum(BVec)
    dist=[ np.array(Y)-a*np.array(AAVec)-b*np.array(BBVec) for Y,a,b in zip(YList,aParams,bParams)  ]
    dist=np.ravel(dist)
    return dist


if __name__=="__main__":

    aList=generate_random_vector(20, sortIt=False)
    bList=generate_random_vector(20, sortIt=False)
    AVec=generate_random_vector(5)
    BVec=generate_random_vector(5)
    YList=[a*AVec+b*BVec for a,b in zip(aList,bList)]

    aGuess=20*[.2]
    bGuess=20*[.3]
    AGuess=5*[.4]
    BGuess=5*[.5]

    bestFitValues, covMX, infoDict, messages ,ier = leastsq(residuals, aGuess+bGuess+AGuess+BGuess ,args=(YList,20,5) ,full_output=True)


    print "a"
    print aList
    besta = bestFitValues[:20]
    print besta

    print "b"
    print bList
    bestb = bestFitValues[20:40]
    print bestb

    print "A"
    print AVec
    bestA = bestFitValues[-2*5:-5]
    realBestA = np.cumsum([x**2 for x in bestA])
    print realBestA

    print "B"
    print BVec
    bestB = bestFitValues[-5:]
    realBestB = np.cumsum([x**2 for x in bestB])
    print realBestB
    print covMX
```

The problem on errors and correlation is that **the solution to the problem is not unique**. If `Y = a A + b B` is a solution and we, e.g., rotate such that `A = c E + s F` and `B = -s E + c F` then also `Y = (ac-bs) E + (as+bc) F =e E + f F` is a solution. The parameter space is, hence, completely flat at "the solution" resulting in huge errors and apocalyptic correlations.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It seems to me it is for one equation (Y=aA+bB) only and not for set of equations (Y=aA+bB, Y'=a'A+b'B, ...) with common A and B.
As far as I understood "constrains" in this solution:
1) I need to able to sort A (from lowest to highest) 
2) and this order need to be the same in both A and B ( A_i>A_j and B_i>B_j for i>j )
3) all element of A and B need to be grater that 0.
Unfortunately 2 and 3 is not possible in my situation.

Comment: @rmrmg My solution is for a set of arbitrary `a`'s and `b`'s with fixed but random `A` and `B`. The elements of `A` and `B` fulfil your points 1), 2), and 3). In the first version I do not have incorporated a1<a2 etc. (note: reversing the order of equations this is equivalent to your a>a'...)
Can you clarify if you want this condition, i.e. a1<a2<a3<... and do you want b1<b2<b3... as well? Is a_i>0 and b_i >0 also required or can they be negative?

Comment: If so, you can use the same trick for `aParams` and `bParams` that I used for `AVec` and `BVec` but still your solution is not unique. Instead of the complicated rotation, you can see that by simple scaling: make all elements of `A` larger by a factor of `u` and divide all `a`'s by `u` doesn't change the `Y`'s...same for `B`. This is because you are looking for a weighted linear combination. With your restriction you decrease the possibilities, but there are still infinite scaled linear combinations giving you the same `Y`'s. The only unchangeable info is the 2D plane that `A` and `B` span.